# Cloud functions and Firebase Firestore with Idempotency

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, idempotent

I'm using Firestore at beta version with Cloud Functions. In my app I need to trigger a function that listens for an `onCreate` event at `/company/{id}/point/{id}` and performs an insert `(collection('event').add({...}))`

My problem is: Cloud Functions with Firestore require an idempotent function. I don't know how to ensure that if my function triggers two times in a row with the same event, I won't add two documents with the same data.

I've found that `context.eventId` could handle that problem, but I don't recognize a way to use it.

```
exports.creatingEvents = functions.firestore
  .document('/companies/{companyId}/points/{pointId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {

    //some logic...

    return db.doc(`eventlog/${context.params.companyId}`).collection('events').add(data)
})
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two things:

1. First check your collection to see if a document has a property with the value of `context.eventId` in it.  If it exists, do nothing in the function.
2. If a document with the event id doesn't already exist, put the value of `context.eventId` in a property in the document that you add.

This should prevent multiple invocations of the function from adding more than one document for a given event id.

Comment: Good answer - and probably as good a guarantee of correctness as you'll get with the `set` approach I outlined if Cloud Functions guarantees no concurrent execution of the same event. The `set` approach saves a network round-trip though, which can matter under load.

Comment: The `set()` approach demands that the body of the function have no variance between executions, else you end up with two different writes.

Comment: Definitely worth pointing out, but I would assume by default that we're interested in the payload that was sent to the function by whatever invoked it, rather than details of the execution context (other than a unique ID for the payload). I'd typically just store the invocation payload rather than the context details unless I had a reason to do otherwise.

Comment: context.eventId always will be unique? Using both approaches I could handle my problem :)

Comment: I'm checking with the Cloud Functions team on how exactly eventId is unique.  I think for your particular case it'll be OK, but there may be some other cases where there's a dup (for example, Firestore ids may not share the same space as Realtime Database ids).

Comment: The event ID should always be unique from a give event provider.  So, all your events coming from Firestore will be unique among themselves, but not necessarily unique when taken in combination with other event providers, such as Realtime Database.

Comment: So this events collection will grow forever... Is there a good way to clean it out as you go without requiring another function?

Answer (score 3):

Why not `set` the document (indexing by the event id from your context) instead of creating it? This way if you write it twice, you'll just overwrite rather than create a new record.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

This approach makes the write operation idempotent.

Comment: Hmm, but with set I need to know the id of document, and currently firestore are doing this for me, but I think if I'm merge your solution with the solution of @doug-stevenson and add a document with the id of the context.eventId I can use "set" and avoid using a new query to check if the document has one property with value of context.eventId

Comment: There's not enough information in the body of the given function to know if two executions will generate the exact same document data.  (If not guaranteed to be exactly the same, then it wouldn't be idempotent.)

Comment: You are correct, but in my case, two executions will generate the same data

Comment: Sounds like you have a plan. Happy we could help :)